# Can't execute submit50

Tags: cs50

I'm taking CS50 web, and I am trying to execute submit50, but I keep getting the same error:

```
You might be using your GitHub password to log in, but that's no longer possible. But you can still use check50 and submit50! See https://cs50.ly/github for instructions.
Make sure your username and/or personal access token are valid and submit50 is enabled for your account. To enable submit50, please go to 
https://submit.cs50.io in your web browser and try again. For instructions on how to set up a personal access token, please visit https://cs50.ly/github
Submission cancelled.
```

I have tried to go to [https://submit.cs50.io](https://submit.cs50.io/) in my web browser and try again. I don't know what to do, I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Just go to https://cs50.ly/github and create a ssh key on your window device. I think linux device will be more suitable as I also use ubuntu. Then you should be able to use submit50. I also face the problem of yours as well.